# map reduce job stuck during sqoop import

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

while  running this sqoop import command

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/training --username training --password training --table cityByCountry
```

on cloudera VM 4.1.1

The mapreduce job is stuck with the last line printed in the terminal 
 mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1450451392672_0001

15/12/17 10:41:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost.localdomain:8088/proxy/application_1450451392672_0001/
15/12/17 10:41:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1450451392672_0001

I tried to track the JOB. Got this returned in the browser!

The requested application does not appear to be running yet, and has not set a tracking URL

how can I debug & solve?

Comment: What happens in log dir of the corresponding job?

Comment: Can you paste the output sqoop command have generated when the job was run?

Comment: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
  manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
  tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
  manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `cityByCountry` AS t LIMIT 1
  manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `cityByCountry` AS t LIMIT 1
  orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop
/tmp/sqoop-training/compile/7c194a69f6fd32b3ef7ff2baac4c564f/cityByCountry.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. here are the first few lines .Thanks4replying

Comment: @avaid thanks for replying . in the log directory there should be 3 files 1)cityByCountry.class 2)cityByCountry.java 3) cityByCountry.jar but in my case the .java file is missing only the .class &.jar  files are there.

Comment: You need to attach the log in a file. It is getting struck in the middle. Once I see the log, I can comment on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it happens due to the load on mysql server. 
Try the same command with **-m 1**

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/training --username training --password training --table cityByCountry -m 1
```